# ArrayList is being cleared and overwritten in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, overwrite

I'm having some trouble in Java.

I have two classes, *suprad* and *coupling*.

Couplings are formed by an ArrayList of *suprad's* (the list is called *supradscoupled*), and two values(integer *num* and double *q*)

Every coupling instantiated is written in an ArrayList called *Createdcouplings*.

During the main program, I have to declare two *couplings* between two *suprad's* each (total of 4 *suprad*'s at all). There is no issue when I declare the first coupling (formed by the two firsts *suprad*'s).

But when I declare the second one trough adding the other two suprad's at the ToBeCoupledSupRads ArrayList, the older couplings are being cleared and then overwritten by the new coupling.

At the end, I get two couplings repeated formed only by the new one.

The MainWindow class:

```
public class MainWindow {
    (...)
    public static List<suprad> ToBeCoupledSupRads = new ArrayList<suprad>();

    public static void main(){
    (...)
    int i = ToBeCoupledComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    suprad stemp = suprad.Createdsuprads.get(i);
    (...)
    // adding new suprad to this ArrayList makes the ArrayList Createdcouplings have its registered data overwritten!
    ToBeCoupledSupRads.add(stemp);
    (...)
    }
}
```

The coupling class:

```
public class coupling {
    public int num;
    public static int total = 0;
    public double q;
    public static List<coupling> Createdcouplings = new ArrayList<coupling>();
    public List<suprad> supradscoupled = new ArrayList<suprad>();

    public coupling(List<suprad> nums, double q)
    {
    (...)
    this.supradscoupled = aux;
    total++;
    this.num = total;
    this.q=q;
    // this is the ArrayList that is having its older data cleared and overwritten unwantedly
    Createdcouplings.add(this);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some help, the Java project is being compiled with JavaSDK 1.8.0_221 with IntelliJ IDEA Community.

Comment: I would review *static* variables in Java.

Comment: You seem to be using static without really understanding what it means and implies. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. If you don't think that's the issue, then post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, with expected and actual output. Please also respect the standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: Please start your class name with upper case and use the camel case convention. Try to better understand  when and where to use the static keyboard.

Comment: I know what is a static variable is, it's not the first time I program, there are other classes in the project that I use these kind of variables and doesn't have problems. Sorry about not respecting the class name convention, but the issue is not being caused by a mispelled Uppercase character.

Comment: The expected result is to have in the ArrayList Createdcouplings two different couplings not two equal couplings.